# Too much whitespace in a table with spreadtab and unitx S

Tags: siunitx, spreadtab, white-space

i made a table where latex creates a big white-space between 2nd and 3rd column. Is there a way to force latex to reduce the width or to let it choose a better width by itself? The numbers themselves in the third column are OK.
Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{spreadtab}
    \usepackage{siunitx}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{r r | S[scientific-notation=fixed, 
      fixed-exponent=-4, round-precision=2, round-mode=places]}}
      \toprule
      {@n1} & {@n2} & {@n2} \\
      \midrule
      88 & 4.3 & \STcopy{v}{b2/a2/a2/ln(a2)} \\
      144 & 10 & \\
      322 & 39 & \\
      692 & 176 & \\
      1498 & 922 & \\
      3180 & 3846 & \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{spreadtab} 

    \end{document}
```

which looks currently like:

[image]

Options from the siunitx package like `table-unit-alignment = left` and `table-number-alignment = left` change either nothing or remove the exponential part of the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `siunitx` how much space it should reserve for the S columns by giving a suitable `table-format`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{r r | S[scientific-notation=fixed, 
fixed-exponent=-4, round-precision=2, round-mode=places, table-format=1.2e-1]}}
\toprule
{@n1} & {@n2} & {@n2} \\
\midrule
88 & 4.3 & \STcopy{v}{b2/a2/a2/ln(a2)} \\
144 & 10 & \\
322 & 39 & \\
692 & 176 & \\
1498 & 922 & \\
3180 & 3846 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab} 

\end{document}
```

[image]